# Location of append operator causing issues

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to append an object `ViewingPost` to an array of these objects. It works when I do what is shown here:

```
     for (_,post) in snap {

                let posst = ViewingPost()

                if let totLikes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String {

                    let postNum = "post" + postID

                    posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                    posst.postID = postID
                    posst.likes = totLikes
                    self.posts.append(posst)

                    for key in 1 ... arr.count {

                        let isEq = arr[key - 1] == postNum
                        print(isEq)
                        if isEq {
                            ref.child(formattedDateD).child(postNum).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapsh) in
                                let snapshP = snapsh.value as! Int

                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Though when I move the part in which it appends the object to the array to where I want it to be, it stops working:

```
           for (_,post) in snap {

                let posst = ViewingPost()

                if let totLikes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String {

                    let postNum = "post" + postID


                    for key in 1 ... arr.count {

                        let isEq = arr[key - 1] == postNum
                        print(isEq)
                        if isEq {
                            ref.child(formattedDateD).child(postNum).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapsh) in
                                let snapshP = snapsh.value as! Int

                                posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                                posst.postID = postID
                                posst.likes = totLikes
                                self.posts.append(posst)
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: How soon are you calling the array after an object is appended? It could be that you're calling it before it has a chance to retrieve the data seeing as it is within the closure.

Comment: There at least four conditions to be true to reach that  line `self.posts.append(posst)`. First you should make sure you debugged your code to reach that line. Secondly, tell us how you are accessing the appended result? Posts will be appended in result of asynchronous calls where you need to make sure you are accessing the posts objects once all the asynchronous calls are done.

Comment: @Kamran I am accessing the appended result by display `posts` on a collection view. Also what do you mean by asynchronous calls? I am not very advanced.